# Regex On Specific char position 241200241511L002

Tags: regex

I have tried this and i need to Find L in position 12,This regexp after 241 not allowed to start with 9 and 50 but now i need to Find L in position 12

```
241200241511L002

^(241)(?![5][0][:.,-]?$)(?![9]?$)(^.{12}[L])\d+$
```

Comment: How about `\d{12}(.*)\d{3}`?

Comment: Can you confirm: the string should have L at position 12, and 241 should not be followed by 9 or 50

Comment: Your regex seems to do a lot more than you describe in your requirements. Can you please complete  your requirements?

Comment: I need to match letter "L" at position 12 and continue to 3 numbers

Comment: ^(241)(?![5][0][:.,-]?$)(?![9]?$)\d+$|^.{11}(L)|^ have a look but this finding L in 12 but does not countinie

Comment: You mean "3 digits", right? Also, what is this condition on punctuation, and why the `$` condition in the negative look ahead. You did not describe that in your requirements. You leave us guessing to your *exact* requirements.

Comment: Maybe be why $  just dont know but my problem is that in every input its passing validation  assume type 9 its going to be validated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following regular expression: `^241(?!9)(?!50)\d{8}[lL]\d+`

[See explanation...](https://regex101.com/r/iy7AQf/2)

[image]

[Here you can visualize your regular expression...](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E241(%3F!9)(%3F!50)%5Cd%7B8%7D%5BlL%5D%5Cd%2B)

Comment: very good answers thank you .but i have and real problem this is in validation field and every input is matched this is full match it will not match if i do no type to the end i need every input

Comment: I do not really understand... Could you give me more correct and wrong examples, please?

Comment: ^(241)(?![5][0][:.,-]?$)(?![9]?$)\d+$|^.{11}(L)|^ Look this is true example but it have problem after L it is not validating

Comment: Do you accept this one: `^(241)(?![5][0][:.,-]?$)(?![9]?$)\d+$|^.{11}(L)\d+ `?

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

You should try out:

```
241(?!50)(?!9)\d{9}[lL]\d{3}
```

As seen at [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/ekz3Vv/2)

## Explanation -

The regex matches 241 at the start, which which should not be followed by 50 or 9.

After `241`, there should be 9 digits, then an `L` at position 12, then 3 digits

Comment: Thank you very much for answer , But this is in validation input and every input is going to match

Answer (score 0):

```
^(241)(?![5][0][:.,-]?$)(?![9]?$)(?!\d{9}[0-9])\d+$|^(241)(.{9}(L))\d+|^(241).{9}(L)|^
```

This is full answer if anyone interested . Matching this number's **241200241511L002** full input